# React native toolbar styling

Tags: react-native, styles

I’m using react native base. I want to centre align the title in iOS and android both, since text is long it hides it with “…”.

I've tried different option unable to fix it. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
 <Header  iosStatusbar="light-content" androidStatusBarColor='#000' >
<Left>
<Button transparent onPress={() =>  this.navigateCustom("goBack")}>
 <Icon name="arrow-back" />
 </Button>
</Left>

    <Body>
     <Title>CLAP TO SUPPORT US</Title>
   </Body>

  <Right>
  <Button transparent onPress={()=> this.navigateCustom("DrawerOpen") }>
     <IconEvil  name={"menu"}  style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)", fontSize:30}}/>
     </Button>
  </Right>
      </Header>
```

[image]

EDIT:

When I apply flex:1 to left right and body it changes nothing but applying flex:4 to body shows the title but it’s not centred

```
 <Header  iosStatusbar="light-content" androidStatusBarColor='#000' >
<Left style={{flex:1}}>
<Button transparent onPress={() =>  this.navigateCustom("goBack")}>
 <Icon name="arrow-back" />
 </Button>
</Left>

    <Body style={{flex:4}}>
     <Title>CLAP TO SUPPORT US</Title>
   </Body>

  <Right style={{flex:1}}>
  <Button transparent onPress={()=> this.navigateCustom("DrawerOpen") }>
     <IconEvil  name={"menu"}  style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)", fontSize:30}}/>
     </Button>
  </Right>
      </Header>
```

Result:
[image]

Applying center alignment:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is what i have tested on my device ios simulator, and Samsung Galaxy S7Edge and emulator.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body  style={{ flex: 4,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'  }}>
            <Title>Title Center</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

> This is what i have tested and result.

I recommend you to check your React-Native package version and compare.

> Here my last version:

```
"native-base": "^2.3.6",
"react": "16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.52.0",
```

[image]

EDIT:
CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Header, Left, Body, Right, Button, Icon, Title } from 'native-base';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='arrow-back' />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body  style={{ flex: 4,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'  }}>
            <Title>Title Center</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right  style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon name='menu' />
            </Button>
          </Right>
        </Header>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

**NEXUS S RESULT**

[image]

Comment: I've used "TEST THIS NATIVE HEADERS" as a title.

Comment: Share me which dependency package you include into your project, then i might have addition idea for you... better then consult you with no clue or your purpose. If keep continue like this, this issue could not be solve. Or u should your source code as possible if i could help you to figure.

Comment: This is what I'm using:                                                                          
                "native-base": "^2.3.3",
  "react": "16.0.0",
  "react-moment": "^0.6.8",
  "react-native": "0.50.3",
  "react-native-base": "^1.1.0",                                                                       See I've used the same source code as your's but Im testing it on NEXUS S now it breaks on it I've added the image to this answer you can view it on edit suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

React Native (NativeBase) follows Android and iOS guidelines,

The title is on the **Left** of the header for **Android** and **Center** for **iOS**.

> If you want it to be in the center, Please apply:
>
> **flex: 1** to `<Left>`, `<Body>` and `<Right>`

Example:

```
<Left style={{ flex: 1 }}>
</Left>

<Body style={{ flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <Title>Home</Title>
</Body>

<Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
</Right>
```

Comment: Please check the edit Answer again... hope it could help

Comment: The title gets sticked to the status bar. See above, applying top padding doesn't show title in center in all devices. @Seyha

Comment: hi @devedv, it's working so fine also with your code.
Please check more carefully dude!!!

Comment: make your title text bit long for eg: "CLAP TO SUPPORT US" also test it on Nexus 5X. Density:420dpi 5.2"

Comment: look your title text is hided with "....." it is not showing completely. That's what Im asking how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: try using emulator NEXUS_5X_API_27. Thank you.

Comment: if you could not solve this and still got problem, you should share your hold source code then I could help to check it for you.

Comment: I've added NEXUS S results using your code. Pls see above. It's hiding the content. Thank you.

Comment: Even if you have any alternative than using native base it would be great. I've tried playing around with views and flex but it doesn't appear to behave same on all devices. Thank you.

Comment: Pls move it to chat. My account don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I have tested all device of Nexus and Pixel, all working very fine.
Here my example Code:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BfJeFe_HXooMpAVPADs74h-TWzynbJ3k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Great! Just replace the title with this "TEST THIS NATIVE HEADERS" . My app title is exactly of this text length. It unfortunately hides. Thanks alot for your help. Applying font size elevates it more towards left or right. After changing the Title only test it on NEXUS S, you will know what I'm trying to tell.

Comment: Works like charm, Thanks alot