# React native base title centre alignment

Tags: react-native, native-base

I’m using react native base. I want to centre align the title in iOS and android both, since text is long it hides it with “…”. Applying `flex:3` shows title fully but it don't centre align it. Even applying `alignItems: 'center',alignSelf: 'center'` don't help.

I've tried different option unable to fix it. How can I fix it?

Code:

```
 <Header  iosStatusbar="light-content" androidStatusBarColor='#000' >
<Left style={{flex:1}}>
<Button transparent onPress={() =>  this.navigateCustom("goBack")}>
 <Icon name="arrow-back" />
 </Button>
</Left>

    <Body style={{flex:3,}}>
     <Title>THIS IS A LONG TITLE TEST</Title>
   </Body>

  <Right style={{flex:1}}>
  <Button transparent onPress={()=> this.navigateCustom("DrawerOpen") }>
     <IconEvil  name={"menu"}  style={{ color: "rgb(255,255,255)", fontSize:30}}/>
     </Button>
  </Right>
      </Header>
```

EDIT:
after applying flex:1 and centre alignment to body
[image]

Answer (score 10):

You could use **justifyContent** and **alignItems** both to **center** like below with `flex:1`:

```
 <Body style={{ flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
   <Title>THIS IS A LONG TITLE TEST</Title>
 </Body>
```

Comment: see above I've added the image after applying flex 1 and center alignment.  <Body style={{ flex: 1,  justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
   <Title>THIS IS A LONG TITLE TEST</Title>
 </Body>

Comment: Hi @devedv please refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378993/react-native-toolbar-styling/48380151#48380151

Answer (score 3):

```
headerTitleStyle:{
      flex:0.8,
      textAlign: 'center',
      alignSelf: 'center',

}
```

You can now style you header title using headerTitleStyle by passing it to navigation options.